# Is there any way to match images against google maps satellite view?

Tags: google-maps

I've got an image that was snapped from google maps satellite view. I know the general location (within a county), but need to find the specific location of the top-down photo.

Are there any tools that can search the google maps satellite images in this given area for a match on the image I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it on Elance, Amazon Mechanical Turk or the like